# Double linked list improvements

Tags: c, memory-leaks, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to improve my double linked list API.

```
int ll_create(linked_list_p list, void (*print_data)(uint8_t)) {
    if (list == NULL) {
        list = calloc(1, sizeof(linked_list_p));
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}

int ll_destroy(linked_list_p list) {
    if (list == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    linked_list_node_p node_ptr = list->tail;

    for(int i = list->size-1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (node_ptr->next) {
            free(node_ptr->next);
            node_ptr->next = NULL;
        }

        node_ptr = node_ptr->previous;

        if (node_ptr->next->previous) {
            node_ptr->next->previous = NULL;
        }

        free(node_ptr->next);
        node_ptr->next = NULL;

    }

    free(list->head);
    list->head = NULL;

    list->size = 0;
    return 0;
}

int ll_get(linked_list_p list, uint32_t index, uint8_t *data){
    if (list == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (index >= list->size) {
        return -1;
    }

    linked_list_node_p node_ptr = list->head;

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++){
        if (node_ptr == NULL) {
            return -1;
        }
        node_ptr = node_ptr->next;
    }

    *data = node_ptr->data.data;

    return 0;
}

int ll_remove(linked_list_p list, uint32_t index) {

    if (list == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (index > list->size-1) {
        return -1;
    }

    linked_list_node_p node_to_delete;

    if (index == 0) {
        node_to_delete = list->head;
        list->head = list->head->next;

        free(list->head->previous);
        list->head->previous = NULL;

        free(node_to_delete->next);
        node_to_delete->next = NULL;
        node_to_delete = NULL;
        free(node_to_delete);

        list->size --;
        return 0;
    }

    if (index == list->size-1) {
        node_to_delete = list->tail;
        list->tail = list->tail->previous;

        free(list->tail->next);
        list->tail->next = NULL;

        free(node_to_delete->previous);
        node_to_delete->previous = NULL;
        free(node_to_delete);
        node_to_delete = NULL;

        list->size --;
        return 0;
    }


    linked_list_node_p node_ptr = list->head;
    for (int i = 0; i < index-1; i++) {
        node_ptr = node_ptr->next;
    }
    node_to_delete = node_ptr->next;

    node_ptr->next->next->previous = node_ptr;
    node_ptr->next = node_ptr->next->next;

    node_to_delete->next = NULL;
    node_to_delete->previous = NULL;
    free(node_to_delete->next);
    free(node_to_delete->previous);

    list->size--;
    
    return 0;
}
```

This is the main : I've tried to test it myself but not sure if its the right way to do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "linked_list.h"



static void print_data(uint8_t data){
    printf("%d", data);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    static linked_list_t list;

    ll_create(&list, print_data);


    ll_add_first(&list, 2);
    ll_insert(&list, 13, 0);
    ll_remove(&list, 32);
    ll_add_last(&list, 3);
    ll_add_last(&list, 4);
    ll_print(&list);
    ll_destroy(&list);
    ll_print(&list);
    ll_add_last(&list, 5);
    ll_add_last(&list, 6);
    ll_add_first(&list, 7);
    ll_print(&list);
    ll_print_backward(&list);
    ll_insert(&list, 8, 4);
    printf("list size : %ld\n", list.size);
    ll_insert(&list, 8, list.size);
    ll_print(&list);

    //TODO use every API functions

    // ll_get
    uint8_t get_data = 0;
    ll_get(&list, 95, &get_data);
    printf("got data : %d\n\n", get_data);

    // ll_remove
    ll_remove(&list, 5);
    ll_print(&list);

    // ll_insert
    ll_insert(&list, 10, 2);
    ll_print(&list);
    // ll_contains
    uint8_t data_to_find = 96;
    printf("The data %d is in the list : %s", data_to_find, ll_contains(&list, data_to_find) ? "true\n" : "false\n");
    data_to_find = 10;
    printf("The data %d is in the list : %s", data_to_find, ll_contains(&list, data_to_find) ? "true\n" : "false\n");
    printf("\n");

    // ll_first_index
    data_to_find = 10;
    printf("The data %d is at node [%d]\n", data_to_find, ll_first_index(&list, data_to_find));
    data_to_find = 96;
    printf("The data %d is at node [%d]\n", data_to_find, ll_first_index(&list, data_to_find));


    // ll_indexes
    ll_add_last(&list, 25);
    ll_add_first(&list, 25);
    ll_insert(&list, 25, list.size);

    ll_print(&list);
    uint32_t *indexes = NULL;
    uint32_t indexes_size = 0;

    if (ll_indexes(&list, 25, &indexes, &indexes_size) == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < indexes_size; i++) {
            printf("%d ", indexes[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(indexes);

    if (ll_indexes(&list, 6, &indexes, &indexes_size) == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < indexes_size; i++) {
            printf("%d ", indexes[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(indexes);

    if (ll_indexes(&list, 7, &indexes, &indexes_size) == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < indexes_size; i++) {
            printf("%d ", indexes[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(indexes);

    ll_destroy(&list);

    ll_destroy(&list);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the header file structs and typedef

```
/**
 * No modification required here
 */
typedef struct data_s{
    uint8_t data;
} data_t;

/**
 * To be implemented : double linked list
 */

struct linked_list_s;
struct linked_list_node_s;

typedef struct linked_list_s linked_list_t;
typedef linked_list_t *linked_list_p;

typedef struct linked_list_node_s linked_list_node_t;
typedef linked_list_node_t *linked_list_node_p;

struct linked_list_node_s{
    linked_list_node_p next;
    linked_list_node_p previous;
    data_t data;
};

struct linked_list_s{
    linked_list_node_p head;
    linked_list_node_p tail;
    size_t size;

    void (*print_data)(uint8_t);
};
```

Why does the ll_create function have a memory leak? In the main, the list was created without nodes. Thus if we call this function, we won't enter the if statement. So how will this have a memory leak?

Comment: *"maybe there's things I've overlooked?"*: this is not really a question that is suitable for Stack Overflow. If you have bumped into a specific problem, then focus your question on that. If there is no apparent problem, you could have a look at the sister site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). But make sure you follow their [guidelines](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) if you post there.

Comment: @Chitong UNG Your code is invalid at least due to the function ll_create

Comment: The code can't be put through a compiler because it is incomplete.

Comment: you're right, I forgot to include the header, where the structs and typedef are defined.

Answer (score 1):

Before improving the quality of your API you need at first to check your code and remove bugs.

For example even the first function `ll_create` in the provided by you code does not make sense and moreover produces a memory leak

```
int ll_create(linked_list_p list, void (*print_data)(uint8_t)) {
    if (list == NULL) {
        list = calloc(1, sizeof(linked_list_p));
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

because the address of the allocated memory is lost after exiting the function.

And for this call of the function in main

```
ll_create(&list, print_data);
```

returns `-1`.

Also the second parameter of the function is not used.

And moreover the second parameter of the call of calloc

```
list = calloc(1, sizeof(linked_list_p)); 
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

is also incorrect.

Or another example. It is unclear why the function `ll_destroy` is called twice in the end of main.

```
ll_destroy(&list);

ll_destroy(&list);
```

that results in undefined behavior because the pointer `tail` within the function does not set to `NULL`.

And it seems this if statement within the function

```
    if (node_ptr->next) {
        free(node_ptr->next);
        node_ptr->next = NULL;
    }
```

does not make sense.

Comment: The main was used to test the API. The function ll_destroy was called a second time was to check if the function would destroy an empty list. To add, linked_list_p is a pointer to struct linked_list_s as shown in the header.

Comment: @Toideki And what? The both functions are invalid and as I pointed out already the first function produces a memory leak.

Comment: I see, it was suppose to be sizeof(linked_list_t) instead. Thank you